# ASP.NET Core policy base Authorize with RequireUser with string array

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am creating policy base authorization and would like to allow multiple users in one policy to access webpage.

I created policy like shown below in start up file. Question, How can I use multiple usernames in one policy? I looked at the method for`.RequireUserName`, it is only accepting string username.

Policy name `AdminServiceAccount` is mostly I am interested in to add multiple users. If I use param `.RequireUserName("DOMAIN\\USER1,DOMAIN\\USER2")` will it work? I don't think so, but wanted to check if there is an alternative way.

```
services.AddAuthorization(
                option =>
                {
                    option.AddPolicy("Admin", policy => policy.RequireRole("Domain\\GroupName"));
                    option.AddPolicy("SuperAdminUser", policy => policy.RequireUserName("DOMAIN\\SuperAdminUser"));
                    option.AddPolicy("AdminServiceAccount", policy => policy.RequireUserName("DOMAIN\\USER1"));
                }
        );
```

**UPDATE 1:**
[image]

**UPDATE 2:**

So in my Controller, I added `[Authorize(Policy = "UserNamesPolicy")]` as show below:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UserNamesPolicy")]
public class ServersController : Controller
{
    private readonly ServerMatrixDbContext _context;

    public ServersController(ServerMatrixDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;    
    }

    // GET: Servers
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        // Some code here
        return View();
    }
}
```

Here is my startup file:

```
services.AddAuthorization(
                option =>
                {
                    option.AddPolicy("UserNamesPolicy",
                                          policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserNamesRequirement("DOMAIN\\USER1", "DOMAIN\\USER2"))
                    );
                }
        );
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesRequirement();
```

For `.AddSingleTon` in startup file I get below error:

[image]

Here is the `handler` class:

```
public class UserNamesHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserNamesRequirement>
{

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserNamesRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userName = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

        if (requirement.Users.ToList().Contains(userName))
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

Here is is the UserNamesRequirement class:

```
public class UserNamesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserNamesRequirement(params string[] UserNames)
    {
        Users = UserNames;
    }
    public string[] Users { get; set; }
}
```

**UPDATE 3:** SOLVED!!!!

Here are few changes that were added from **update 2**:

In `UserNameshandler` class changed var userName to get values from `context.User.Identity.Name;`

```
public class UserNamesHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserNamesRequirement>
{

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserNamesRequirement requirement)
    {
        // var userName = context.User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;

        if (requirement.Users.ToList().Contains(userName))
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

In StartUp class fixed from `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesRequirement>();` to `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler,UserNamesHandler>();`

Thanks to Gevory. :)

Comment: use services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesHandler>() instead of services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesRequirementr>()

Comment: Thank you. Now I am able to get in to the handler. Are you in chat group? Sent some details there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
public class UserNamesHandler : AuthorizationHandler<UserNamesRequirement>
{
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, UserNamesRequirement requirement)
    {
        var userName = context.User.Identity.Name;
        if(requirement.UserNames.ToList().Contains(userName))
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask; // if it does not compile use Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

public class UserNamesRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public UserNamesRequirement(params string[] userNames)
    {
        UserNames = userNames;
    }

    public string[] UserNames { get; set; }
}
```

in startup.cs add the following

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("UserNamesPolicy",
                                  policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new UserNamesRequirement("ggg","dsds")));
            });
           services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesHandler>()

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time for this awesome code. :) so in `UserNameHandler` class, I am getting `CompletedTask is not in Task`. I have updated my query with screenshot with error I am getting.

Comment: you can use Task.FromResult(0) then

Comment: @Ray I am using asp.net core so there can be some little differences, if you are getting some other errors let me know

Comment: Thanks Gevory. So far I was able to implement code suggested by you, but when I browse the controller, I get `403`, and still troubleshooting whats the issue here. Also I wanted to let you know that I am relaying on `User.Identity.Name` to get windows user. Do I need to add this `services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesRequirement>();` as well in startup as well?

Comment: Please Set breakpoint in handler and check are you getting correct username?

Comment: Thanks. :) will add Update 2 in my question with more details shortly to show what I have done so far. I added break point in handle, but for some reason it didnt go in there, I think it is maybe because `AddSingleTon` was not loaded. When I add `AddSingleton` in startup I get an error.

Comment: services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, UserNamesHandler>()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125862/discussion-between-gevorg-narimanyan-and-ray).

Comment: Task.Completed task is a short cut;

#if NET451
        public static readonly Task CompletedTask = Task.FromResult(0);
#else
        public static readonly Task CompletedTask = Task.CompletedTask;
#endif

Answer (score 1):

Just for anyone coming to this who wants a different approach, I battled with trying to get the `UserNamesHandler` to register properly, to no avail. So I solved this in a different way:

```
static readonly string[] myUserList = { "user1", "user2", "user3" };

options.AddPolicy( "MyNameListPolicy", 
          policy => policy.RequireAssertion( 
                context => myUserList.Contains( context.User.Identity.Name ) ) );
```

This worked fine for me.